# ChartJS Multiple Line from PHPMyAdmin

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have 2 datasets.

Date and Value.

Date is on the X Axis
Value is on the Y Axis.

The dates don't always match up and my current code isn't drawing the line past the missing dates.

```
First Data Set:
a1 = ['2021-12-10','2021-12-11','2021-12-12','2021-12-13','2021-12-14','2021-12-15','2021-12-16']
a2 = [33,11,22,22,33,44,55]

Second Data Set:
aa1 = ['2021-12-10','2021-12-11','2021-12-12','2021-12-13','2021-12-14','2021-12-16']
aa2 = [77,55,88,22,99,55]
```

What is happening,
The graph is missing the 15th Date.

What should be happening is first data set to have the 15th date point and the second data set going from the 14th to the 16th
[Image of the current graph here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIMGI.png)

Below is my ChartJS code.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>
<script>

var xValues = <?php echo '['.$a1.']'; ?>;
var yValues = <?php echo '['.$a2.']'; ?>;

var xxValues = <?php echo '['.$aa1.']'; ?>;
var yyValues = <?php echo '['.$aa2.']'; ?>;



new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: xValues,
    datasets: [{
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1.0)",
      borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.1)",
      data: yValues
    },
    {
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(216,104,104,1)",
      borderColor: "rgba(216,104,104,1)",
      data: yyValues
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {display: true, text: 'Title'},
    legend: {display: false},
    
                
                
                    
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{ticks: {min: 10, max:100}}],
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried using mapping the data values. `data: yValues to data: yValues.map((v, i) => ({ x: xValues[i], y: v })),
and data:yyValues to data: yyValues.map((v, i) => ({ x: xxValues[i], y: v })),`

What happens on this, Instead of the second dataset missing the 15th going from 14th to the 16th, It finishes on the 15th and misses the 16th date

Comment: Due to you  are using a date as X, why don't you use time scale as xAxes? By default, line is using the linear one. With time scale, I think you will have all data. Otherwise, you could normalize the "labels" in order to have all values of all axes